# Views slideshow + ajax content

Tags: ajax, views

if there any solution for this?
I need to do views slideshow with content loading (with ajax).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Flex Slider module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider). It provides this functionality, but you might need to theme it a little bit. A screenshot similar to what you want is below. Note that you are not limited to pictures, but you can use any type of content in the display.

[image: Sample picture]

It is quite a hassle to start with at first, but I found these youtube videos very valuable:

Basic set-up instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MboDby9-PCE

Theming guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Jukg7UlSZA

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jcarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module. You can use it for views and you will get required output. Have a look at [examples of jcarouscel slider](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/).